# How can I access the configurations of a .qmdl logfile?

Tags: lte, 4g

I am using QCAT to view log files and filtering them based on what I need to look at. For a specific record, I need to extract the configurations, but I cannot find the configurations when I decode the logfile.
[image]

I need to extract everything between the curly braces as the configs, but they seem to be hidden within the XML I decoded the logfile into. I then converted it to a Python dictionary but still could not find them. The key/value pairs (e.g. latitudeSign north) literally do not exist in the decoded logfile, so I am assuming they may be hidden within a deeper level I am not opening, but I thought I fully decoded the XML, so I am stuck.

Does anyone know if there is possibly another layer of decoding/filtering I might need to do? Why do the configs between the curly braces show up in neither the XML nor the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

> split( { } )

method?

Comment: At the moment, this answer would be more suitable as a comment... To help people in the future, it's customary to add a bit more explanation as to what this code does to make it more authoritative.